Select the maximum among the column fields
I have created a variable like below to accommodate multiple varchar values.
DECLARE
  TYPE t_refField10 IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (25);
  v_refField10 t_refField10;
BEGIN
  SELECT REF_FIELD_10 BULK COLLECT INTO v_refField10 FROM LPN  WHERE 
  TC_ASN_ID = v_asnId;
END;

The want maximum of ref_field_10 value.
But the catch is :
ref_field_10 values are varchar type and they are something like this.
enter image description here
They are in YYYYMMDD-HRS format.
Here 20220409-16 means 9th April 2022 4 PM.
20220411-09 means 11th April 2022  9 AM.
I need to find max of ref_field_10 (ref_field_10 which has latest date time).
Can someone help me here?
I have no idea how to achieve this.

Lots of options. Your string-formatted date is already alphabetically in the same sort order as a real date, so a simple MAX or ORDER BY or GREATEST works just fine out of the box. To get the value you could:

Define your collection as a SQL type and then query the populated collection directly with SQL (the column name will literally be "COLUMN_VALUE"):
create TYPE t_refField10 IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (25);

DECLARE
  v_refField10 t_refField10;
  var_maxvalue varchar2(25);
BEGIN
  SELECT REF_FIELD_10 BULK COLLECT INTO v_refField10 FROM LPN  WHERE 
  TC_ASN_ID = v_asnId;

  SELECT MAX(column_value)
    INTO var_maxvalue
    FROM TABLE(v_refField10);

  dbms_output.put_line(var_maxvalue);
END;


Do a separate query from your collection population just to get the max
DECLARE
  TYPE t_refField10 IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (25);
  v_refField10 t_refField10;
  var_maxvalue varchar2(25);
BEGIN
  SELECT REF_FIELD_10 BULK COLLECT INTO v_refField10 FROM LPN  WHERE 
  TC_ASN_ID = v_asnId;

  SELECT MAX(REF_FIELD_10) INTO var_maxvalue FROM LPN  WHERE 
  TC_ASN_ID = v_asnId;

  dbms_output.put_line(var_maxvalue);
END;


Add a descending ORDER BY clause to your collection population and then grab the first array index:
DECLARE
  TYPE t_refField10 IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (25);
  v_refField10 t_refField10;
  var_maxvalue varchar2(25);
BEGIN
  SELECT REF_FIELD_10 BULK COLLECT INTO v_refField10 FROM LPN  WHERE 
  TC_ASN_ID = v_asnId ORDER BY REF_FIELD_10 DESC;

  var_maxvalue := v_refField10(1); -- or v_refField10(v_refField10.FIRST)
  dbms_output.put_line(var_maxvalue);
END;


Loop through the collection in PL/SQL:
 DECLARE
   TYPE t_refField10 IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (25);
   v_refField10 t_refField10;
   var_maxvalue varchar2(25) := ' ';
 BEGIN
   SELECT REF_FIELD_10 BULK COLLECT INTO v_refField10 FROM LPN  WHERE 
   TC_ASN_ID = v_asnId;

   FOR i IN v_refField10.FIRST .. v_refField10.LAST
   LOOP
     var_maxvalue := GREATEST(v_refField10(i),var_maxvalue);
   END LOOP;

   dbms_output.put_line(var_maxvalue);
 END;




IF you want the max value to be in DATE format you can use the below
 SELECT MAX(to_Date(REF_FIELD_10,'YYYYMMDD-HH24'))  INTO v_date_field FROM 
 LPN  WHERE TC_ASN_ID = v_asnId;

